# getting Cannot read property 'done' of undefined from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have this ajax call which send data from an input element to the server

```
function upload_files() {
    let form_data = new FormData($('#form_upload')[0]); // wieso [0] ? == alle inputs auf einmal
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/receave_files_lambda',
        data: form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json", // 
        success: flask_return_data => insertdata(flask_return_data)//
        });
}
```

which returns successfully a Json string,

I want to append callback functions if the call is successful
by  decoupling the success function using `done()`

```
$(function (){
   $("#do_upload").on("click", function (){
       let ajax_promise = upload_files();
       ajax_promise.done(function (data){
           console.log(data);
       })
   })

});

function upload_files () {
}
```

which gave me an

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined`

what causes the error ?

Comment: You can call `done()` on the return value of `$.ajax()`. You aren't doing anything with that value. You don't have a `return` statement for `upload_files_lab()` so it returns `undefined`. You haven't included `upload_files()` (although I assume that's another typo). If you want to do something with the return value of `$.ajax` outside the function you call it in, you need to return it.

Comment: Strange that you're not getting a `Uncaught ReferenceError: upload_files is not defined` error

Comment: @AlonEitan was an typo

Comment: So now just add `return $.ajax({ ....` and it should work

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you return nothing from your method "upload_files".

So you define `$.ajax({...})` but you forgot to return it.

change your upload_files method to the following and it should work fine.

```
function upload_files() {
    let form_data = new FormData($('#form_upload')[0]); // wieso [0] ? == alle inputs auf einmal
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/receave_files_lambda',
        data: form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json", // 
        success: flask_return_data => insertdata(flask_return_data)//
        });
}
```